# Pink E.coli cell pellet. Reasons?

Tags: microbiology, cell-culture, recombinant

I've harvested IPTG induced E.coli BL21DE3 cells' suspension culture by spinning at 5000 rpm/15 min/4 degrees C. The pellet after spin looked pale pink colored. What could be the reasons?

Comment: If you induced them with IPTG what additional genes had you added to induce?

Comment: That would be my question as well: What do you overexpress in the cells?

Comment: I've seen E. coli colonies with red fluorescent protein that were visibly red even without UV light. That assumes you have cells with RFP. I've heard of [carotenoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carotenoid) making bacteria red too, but I don't know what would happen to make E. coli produce them.

Comment: There are a few possibilities why the cells can be pink, so it would be important to know which gene is overexpressed.